# Making Both Value to be Condition for django_filters in DRF and Showing Customized Error if the condition is empty

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filters

I am trying to use Filter in Django Restful Framework using `django_filters`. I would like to use two fields so the condition must be met for both fields. This means the user must enter `ref_code` and `expecting_time`. But now, if the user enters `ref_code` the query still works. Lastly, if the query is empty I need a customized Message.

filters.py

```
import django_filters
from myappointment.models import *

class AppointmentFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    
    class Meta:
        model = AppointmentData
        fields =['ref_code', 'expecting_time']
```

api.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def AllAppointmentData(request):
    queryset = AppointmentData.objects.all()
    filterset = AppointmentFilter(request.GET, queryset=queryset)

    if filterset.is_valid():
        queryset = filterset.qs
        if queryset is not None:
            serializer = AppointmentDataSerializer(queryset, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response([], {'success': "The Query is empty"}, status=status.HTTP_200_BAD_REQUEST )
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Y5pC.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters

class AppointmentFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
      ref_code = filters.CharFilter(field_name="ref_code", required=True)
      expecting_time = filters.DateFilter(field_name="expecting_time", required=True)
```

Comment: NameError: name 'filters' is not defined. Did you mean: 'filter'?

Comment: @CouoneTechnology modified my answer

Comment: Then, how do I customized my message if queryset = filterset.qs is empty

Comment: in your api.py you can handle it. `if not self.get_queryset().exist() return Response("empty")`